# Html, Vue, Laravel - loop in v-for and table

Tags: php, html, laravel, vue.js

I hava a simple table, every tr is a link with a sepcific order, but I have to have one extra column n th with checking or this order is already in store. ( with checboxes ) I can't to this because when I add this, then all row i a link, but I want to this last column wasn't a link, but simple checboxes. 
Here is my code:

```
<table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Order Number</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Tel</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Order date</th>
                <th>IS in store?</th>
            </tr>

            <router-link :to="'/orderDetail/'+order.id" tag="tr" v-for="order in orders" :key="order.number"
                         class="order-row">
                <td>{{order.number}}</td>
                <td>{{order.client_name}}</td>
                <td>{{order.phone}}</td>
                <td>{{order.email}}</td>
                <td>{{order.actual_status}}</td>
                <td>{{order.order_date}}</td>
                <td>Here should be checbox with id of roder, but not as a link</td>
            </router-link>

        </table>
```

html css :

```
  .order-row:hover td {
  cursor: pointer;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  background-color: #EfEEEE;
  border-top: 1px solid #e0093e;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e0093e;
  color: #e0093e;
```

}

Comment: Which Vuejs version you have used? 1 or 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create one method, something like this

```
        orderRedirect: function(order) {
            this.$router.replace('/orderDetail/' + order.id); // For Vuejs 2
            this.$route.router.go('/orderDetail/' + order.id); //For Vuejs 1
        },
```

Then call this function on click from table td, something like this

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Order Number</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Tel</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Order date</th>
        <th>IS in store?</th>
    </tr>
    <tr v-for="order in orders" class="order-row">
        <td @click="orderRedirect(order)" style="cursor: pointer">{{order.number}}</td>
        <td @click="orderRedirect(order)" style="cursor: pointer">{{order.client_name}}</td>
        <td @click="orderRedirect(order)" style="cursor: pointer">{{order.phone}}</td>
        <td @click="orderRedirect(order)" style="cursor: pointer">{{order.email}}</td>
        <td @click="orderRedirect(order)" style="cursor: pointer">{{order.actual_status}}</td>
        <td @click="orderRedirect(order)" style="cursor: pointer">{{order.order_date}}</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is one of way that you can remove link from checkbox td

Comment: It's okey, but plis check my css, when someone hover over the tr then all td have special backround - include input type checbox, is there a possibility to have this column "is in store" withous this hover styles?

Comment: without hover you can use something like this `<table class="table table-hover">`  But it's not give same hover style as per your css so it's better to use this css cass

Answer (score 1):

Try something along the lines of:

```
<td><input type="checkbox" v-model="order.actual_status"></td>
```